# Checking username and password is correct from a text file

Tags: python

I need to check that the usernames and passwords match up with the details in a text file. I'm not sure how to do this. Here is what i have so far (saving the username to the file).

```
print("Are you a returning player?")
user = input()
if user.lower() == "no":
    username = input("Please enter a username for your account.\n")
    password = input("Please enter a password for your account.\n")
    file = open("account.txt","a")
    file.write(username)
    file.write("\n")
    file.write(password)
    file.close()

else:
 user_name = input("Please enter your username.\n")
 pass_word = input("Please enter your password.\n")
```

Comment: You have the writing to the file figured out. Now you should google "how to read from a file in python".

Comment: Welcome! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]. Mainly you haven't shown effort on reading the file you created

Comment: I'd also recommend you check out the OWASP guidelines for storing passwords before deciding to use a text file. It's good to learn how to read variables out of files, but it definitely isn't a secure way to do things!

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @benjamin You aren't wrong, but I think that's a little out of scope for the level the OP's at. Hitting newbies with higher level stuff early on does not encourage learning, rather just confusion and frustration.

Comment: @Aaron fair point!

Comment: @Aaron the point of this site is not for a personal help desk, it's point is to provide resource for future readers. People at all skill levels should learn that you shouldn't store plain passwords in text file as it's not a good idea. "Hitting newbies with higher level stuff early on" doesn't really apply here since that's not the point of the site :\. OP can choose to read it and learn or they can choose to ignore it. But we should encourage posts like Benjamin.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method using `with open` that close your file after the procedures are done inside the loop, so you can create a read loop and an append loop. For this I like the idea of storing the name and password on the same line, that way we can check to make sure the name and corresponding password are linked to each other rather than being able to use any password for any name. Also when using append we are going to have to add a `'\n'` or everything we `write` will be written to the same line

To verify the user we open the file as `r` and then we can use `for line in f` to get all the lines in the `.txt` from there we can loop through each line and if both username and password exist in the same line, we can welcome the user, if not send them back to the beginning.

Hope this helps!

```
while True:
    user = input('\nAre you a returning player: ')
    if user.lower() == 'no':
        with open('accounts.txt', 'a') as f:
            username = input('\nEnter username: ')
            password = input('Enter password: ')
            combo = username + ' ' + password
            f.write(combo + '\n')

    else:
        with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as f:
            username = input('\nEnter username: ')
            password = input('Enter password: ')
            for line in f:
                if username + ' ' + password + '\n' == line:
                    print('Welcome')
                    break
            else:
                print('Username and/or Password Incorrect')
```

> ```
> Are you a returning player: no
>
> Enter username: vash
> Enter password: stampede
>
> Are you a returning player: yes
>
> Enter username: vash
> Enter password: stacko
> Username and/or Password Incorrect
>
> Are you a returning player: yes
>
> Enter username: vash
> Enter password: stampede
> Welcome
> ```

Comment: Just a few nitpicks.. the file: 'accounts.txt' doesn't have any newlines (opening in append mode does not insert `'\n'`), and the previous password will run together with the next username. As a result of it all being one line, you also don't check if the password is actually associated with the given user as every username and every password is on the only line. I could presumably use my password with anyone else's username :/ Finally if you intend on iterating line by line anyway it's simpler to just user `for line in f:` than calling `f.readlines()` and iterating over the result.

Comment: Also your line `if username and password in i:` doesn't do anything close to what you think... it's equivelent to `if bool(username) and (password in line):` *note parenthesis for order of operation. and if `password` is just required to be a substring of `line`, quite a lot could pass as the password.

Comment: @Aaron now I'm here fixing a user/password demo, and missing out on all these dictionary retrivals,

Comment: @Aaron nice edit but still if the else comes before the match we will get the incorrect statement also that write needs to be write `combo + '\n'`

Comment: yah, you can make that change. you should also update your text at the beginning to match the code.

Comment: @Aaron we are taking this too far, soon we are going to be encrypting and OP going to be lost hehehe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180695/discussion-between-aaron-and-vash-the-stampede).